# Why is this exit indicator placed here?

Tags: emergency, boeing-737, cabin-design, cabin

[image]

Some  Boeing 737s have this exit indicator in the cabin, attached in a seemingly odd position, next to the overhead bins, instead of in the middle.

Why is it placed here?

Comment: Some guesses 1) It looks like it's easier to attach the sign to the smooth curve of the roof section there than the lumpy rail right down the middle. 2) There may already be "emergency" type wiring (connected to batteries) running along that part of the roof, so not making a connection to the center of the fuselage saves weight of extra wiring.

Comment: "People who speak (assumingly) Mandarin must exit to the left, English speakers to the right"

Comment: @RonBeyer LOL! Hadn't even noticed that...

Comment: Really...?? Joke..? LOL..KKKKKK @RonBeyer

Comment: Thank you very much ;)) @FreeMan

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53826/62), although I don't think it's a dupe

Comment: @RonBeyer It's Korean writing :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont have this tagged with a jurisdiction and the answer may vary a bit by country regulations but here in the US under the FAA the requirements do not explicitly state the sign must be in the middle of the aircraft:

> [**§ 25.812 Emergency lighting.**](http://%C2%A7%2025.812%20Emergency%20lighting.)
>
> (b)Emergency exit signs -
>
> (1) For airplanes that have a passenger seating configuration, excluding pilot seats, of >10 seats or more must meet the following requirements:
>
> (i) Each passenger emergency exit locator sign required by § 25.811(d)(1) and each 
>   passenger emergency exit marking sign required by § 25.811(d)(2) must
>   have red letters at least 1 1/2 inches high on an illuminated white
>   background, and must have an area of at least 21 square inches
>   excluding the letters. The lighted background-to-letter contrast must
>   be at least 10:1. The letter height to stroke-width ratio may not be
>   more than 7:1 nor less than 6:1. These signs must be internally
>   electrically illuminated with a background brightness of at least 25
>   foot-lamberts and a high-to-low background contrast no greater than
>   3:1.
>
> (ii) Each passenger emergency exit sign required by § 25.811(d)(3)
>   must have red letters at least 1 1/2 inches high on a white background
>   having an area of at least 21 square inches excluding the letters.
>   These signs must be internally electrically illuminated or
>   self-illuminated by other than electrical means and must have an
>   initial brightness of at least 400 microlamberts. The colors may be
>   reversed in the case of a sign that is self-illuminated by other than
>   electrical means.

So if its easier due to electronic cabling, head room, brackets, or any other factor manufacturers are free to mount the sign off center.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest!! @DAVE